# Xcode 12 broke multiline guard indentation in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, indentation, xcode12

With one line guard Xcode 12 make right indentation:

```
guard let contentName = vod.name else {
    Log.fault("No data.")
    return
}
```

but with multiline, the indentation is **broken**:

```
guard let contentName = vod.name,
      let season = vod.season else {
          Log.fault("No data.")
          return
      }
```

Am I doing something wrong or there are someone with the same problem?

Comment: I've made a feedback: `FB9974879 (Indentation wrong for multiline.)` in https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/9974879

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Xcode Version 13.3.1 (13E500a)** it seems to be fixed

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this with Xcode 13.1

Interestingly it works fine for multi-line `if let`.

The "Preferences/Text Editing/Indentation"-menu does not offer any option to fix this.

I have submitted a bug report in the Apple feedback assistant (FB9958961, it's probably non-public?).
I am afraid that is all we can do at this point:

- raise awareness for the issue through a Stack Overflow posting ✅
- file a bug report ✅
- consider using AppCode instead of Xcode …